# How to use WriteableBitmapExtension library to blur image on Windows Phone?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, blur

This seems not working?

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(albumArtImage);
WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(wb, WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);
AlbumBackground.ImageSource = wb;
```

Comment: What is it doing? What have you tried?

Comment: The code is to blur an image using WriteablebitmapExtension library. The answer below fixed the problem I had. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(albumArtImage);
var wb2 = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(wb, WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);
AlbumBackground.ImageSource = wb2;
```