# How to use WriteableBitmapExtension library to blur image?

Tags: image, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

This is giving me no result. What's wrong with the code? [BTW, the below code blurs the image.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000616/how-to-use-writeablebitmapextension-library-to-blur-image-on-windows-phone)

```csharp
var ImgFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/search.png"));
var wb = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
using (var strm = await ImgFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
    wb.SetSource(strm);
}
var wb2 = new WriteableBitmap(wb.PixelWidth,wb.PixelHeight);
var wb3 = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(wb2, WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);
PageBackground.Source = wb3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the image into wb image but you are not using it to blur (instead you are just blurring wb2 which is empty).
This should work:

```cs
var ImgFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/search.png"));
var wb = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
using (var strm = await ImgFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
     wb=await wb.FromStream(strm);
}
var wb3 = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(wb, WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);
PageBackground.Source = wb3;
```

Comment: Getting `System.AccessViolationException - Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

Comment: I just tried the code and if you add a breakpoint after the SetSource you willl notice that the WriteableBitmap is not yet loaded (the number of pixel is set but the buffer is not yet filled), as a workaround using  wb=await wb.FromStream(strm); seem to work. Otherwise you can also load the Stream into memory and set using a MemoryStreaam in SetSource and it should work too.